# PHP: Uncaught SoapFault exception

Tags: php, web-services, soap

So I am trying to create a SOAP Client/Server in PHP but I am getting the following error.. PS, I know that others have also asked this question and got some responses and i looked into them however, the answers given didn't fix my error that's why i am posting this question.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in C:\xamppp\htdocs\C\project\client.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xamppp\htdocs\C\project\client.php(11): SoapClient->__soapCall('getUsersName', Array) #1 C:\xamppp\htdocs\C\project\service.php(5): client->getName(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xamppp\htdocs\C\project\client.php on line 11
```

and here are my codes for server.php:

```
<?php

class server
{
    private $con;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->con=(is_null($this->con)) ? self::connect() : $this->con;
    }
    static function connect()
    {
        $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
        $db=mysql_select_db('soap',$con);
        return $con;
    }

    public function getUsersName($id)
    {
        $id=trim($id['id']);
        $sql = "SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE ID = '$id'";
        $qry = mysql_query($sql, $this->con);
        $res = mysql_fetch_array($qry)
        return $res['name'];
    }
}
$params=array('uri'=>'http://localhost:40/C/project/server.php');
$server= new SoapServer(NULL, $params);
$server->setClass('server');
$server->handle();

?>
```

and here is for client.php:

```
<?php
class client
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $params=array('location'=>'http://localhost:40/C/project/server.php','uri'=>'urn//localhost:40/cpu6003/project/server.php','trace'=>1);
        $this->instance= new SoapClient(NULL,$params);
    }
    public function getName($id)
    {
        return $this->instance->__soapCall('getUsersName',$id);
    }
}
$client= new client;
?>
```

and lastly, service:

```
<?php
include './client.php';
$id=array('id' => '1');

echo $client->getName($id);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your server logs, server.php is probably throwing some error and it will tell what's wrong.

I suspect it may be this line:

```
$sql = "SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE ID = '$id'";
```

Try changing it to something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE ID = " . (int)$id;
```